# Consecutive Post request node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post, routes

I wanted to know that 
Can i do consecutive post requests in separate route file and with each post request redirect to a different ejs page.

This is my file structure

routes:-index.js

-users.js

-users1.js

views:-index.ejs

-users.ejs

-users1.ejs

this is my app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var users1 = require('./routes/users1');
var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/users1', users1);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

this is my index.js

```
`var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index');
});
router.post('/users', function(req, res, next) {
  res.redirect('/users');
});
module.exports = router;`
```

This is my index.ejs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="/users" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="post">
     </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

this is my users.js

```
    var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('users');
});
router.post('/users1', function(req, res, next) {
  res.redirect('/users1');
});
module.exports = router;
```

this is my users.ejs

```
    <html>
  <head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
     <form action="/users1" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="post">
     </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

this is my users1.js

```
    var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

  res.render('users1');
});
module.exports = router;
```

this is my users1.ejs

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
<h1>hello</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

the post request from index.ejs to users.ejs is working fine and it is redirecting to users.ejs 
but the request from users.ejs to users1.ejs is not working .
and it shows 404 not found
this is the entire console.log output

```
> hostelSystem@0.0.0 start /home/ritwik/hostelSystem
> node ./bin/www

POST /users 302 43.621 ms - 56
GET /users 200 10.041 ms - 205
GET /stylesheets/style.css 304 2.742 ms - -
POST /users1 404 16.965 ms - 946
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like in your users1 router you are using the router.get you probably want to use router.post because you are requesting domain.com/users1 it goes directly to this router only, and i only notice now that you dont need the forwarding because when you call domain.com/users it goes directly to the users router

```
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('users1');
});
module.exports = router;
```